# How to run Linux GUI on macos

Tags: unix, docker

I'm following this website's instruction so I can run Linux gui app on my mac:

https://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-run-a-linux-gui-application-on-osx-using-docker/

I've downloaded Kitematic (v0.17.7) and docker toolbox (v19.03.1) from github.

https://github.com/docker/kitematic/releases

https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases

However, when I enter `docker pull kartoza/qgis-desktop`  on the terminal, I get the following error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you open a new Terminal tab before pulling?

Comment: that seemed to solve the issue!

Comment: Now I am getting a new issue though. When I want to run the QGIS docker container as indicated in https://kartoza.com/en/blog/how-to-run-a-linux-gui-application-on-osx-using-docker/, I get the error "docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/Users/timlinux': mkdir /Users/timlinux: protocol error"